# screen turn off after using "WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON"

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, android-wake-lock

I'm having problem allow the device to dim and turn off after using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`.

I've built a recording camera and while recording I don't want the screen to turn off so I used the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` and its work fine.
The problem is that after recording (while still in the same activity) I wand to set the device to the previous state (after couple of seconds dim, after couple of seconds more then it completely off).
I follow this android code:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

and its says to use `getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)`, but nothing happens and the screen is kept on.

Anyone knows how to let the screen turn off?

Here is my code:

```
 private View.OnClickListener startRecord=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isRecording) {
            // stop recording and release camera
            mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

            // inform the user that recording has stopped

            isRecording = false;
            videoV.setAlpha(1f);
            videoV.setClickable(true);
            videoX.setAlpha(1f);
            videoX.setClickable(true);
            toggleRecord.setAlpha(0f);
            toggleRecord.setClickable(false);
            timerCountDown.cancel();//chancel timer counter
            animationCountDown.cancel();//chancel animation counter
            videoCountDown.setText("");
            videoCounterFrame.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));  // set counter alpha to 0
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);  // after recording, allow screen turn off
        } else {
            // initialize video camera
            if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                // now you can start recording
                toggleRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.vidcam_stop);
                mMediaRecorder.start();

                // inform the user that recording has started

                isRecording = true;
                videoCounterFrame.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));//set alpha to 0.3
                //init two animations- first change animation from white to red and second the opposite
                final ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#f50f2b"));
                colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                        videoCountDown.setTextColor((Integer)animator.getAnimatedValue());
                    }

                });

                final ValueAnimator colorAnimation2 = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.parseColor("#f50f2b"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                colorAnimation2.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                        videoCountDown.setTextColor((Integer)animator.getAnimatedValue());
                    }

                });
                //start both counters
                timerCountDown=new CountDownTimer(121000, 100) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        Log.i("millis",millisUntilFinished+"");
                        if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)>0){
                            videoCountDown.setText(String.format("%d:%02d",
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
                        }else{

                            videoCountDown.setText((millisUntilFinished-1000)/1000+"");
                        }

                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        videoCountDown.setText("0");
                        toggleRecord.performClick();
                    }
                }.start();

                animationCountDown=new CountDownTimer(121000, 600) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        if(animationColorChange){
                            colorAnimation.start();
                            animationColorChange=false;
                        }else{
                            colorAnimation2.start();
                            animationColorChange=true;
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        animationColorChange=true;
                    }

                }.start();

            } else {
                // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                // inform user
            }
        }
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); // screen never goes to sleep while recording
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post your code here!

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210224163252/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html) to dim the light.
Some snippets are :(brightness is an integer value)

```
  IHardwareService hardware = IHardwareService.Stub.asInterface(
  ServiceManager.getService("hardware"));
  if (hardware != null) {
    hardware.setScreenBacklight(brightness);
  }
```

Another Way is :

```
Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),
    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 20);

   WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
  lp.screenBrightness =0.2f;// 100 / 100.0f;
  getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: can I override it later and return it to system default?

Answer (score 0):

You could play with some View using in your xml the attribute keepScreenOn. In this way when the view is no more visible the flag is no more valid automatically. [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3AkeepScreenOn)

Comment: I try it, it keeps the screen on, but still after couple of seconds the dim reduce and the screen turn dark.